# datetime plot with errorbars in pandas

Tags: datetime, numpy, matplotlib, pandas

I'm trying to plot a dataframe which has datetime index with *x*- and *y* errors.

Consider the following minimal example, I want errorbars of 1/2 day beacause the data is binned in this range:

```
from pandas import DataFrame
import numpy as np
import datetime

start = np.datetime64("2014-01-1")
stop = start + np.timedelta64(100, "D")

df = DataFrame()
df["y"] = np.random.normal(0, 1, 100)
df.index = np.arange(start, stop)
df["y"].plot()
```

but everything i tried caused errors, like

```
xerr = np.timedelta64(0.5, "D")
xerr = np.timedelta64(12, "h")
xerr = datetime.timedelta(days=0.5)
```

So how can i achieve errorbars of length 1/2 day?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using just the `pandas.DataFrame.plot(xerr=)`, the error bars work so long as the `pandas.Timedelta` is in the same units as the `DatetimeIndex` Freq.

I get 2 plots of the form I think you want from the code below:

```
from pandas import DataFrame, date_range, Timedelta
import numpy as np

rng = date_range(start='2014-01-01', periods=5, freq='24H')
df = DataFrame({'y':np.random.normal(size=len(rng))}, index=rng)
terr = Timedelta(hours=12)
ax = df['y'].plot(xerr=len(df)*[terr])


rng2 = date_range(start='2014-01-01', periods=5, freq='D')
df2 = DataFrame({'y':np.random.normal(size=len(rng))}, index=rng)
terr2 = Timedelta(days=0.5)
ax2 = df2['y'].plot(xerr=len(df2)*[terr2])
```

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if it is possible using the `pandas.DataFrame.plot()` method. 
It can be done calling `matplotlib` directly:

```
from pandas import DataFrame, date_range, Timedelta
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

rng = date_range(start='2014-01-01', periods=100, freq='D')
df = DataFrame({'y':np.random.normal(size=len(rng))}, index=rng)

terr = Timedelta(hours=12)
yerr = 0.05

fig, ax = plt.subplots()
ax.errorbar(df.index, df.y, xerr=terr)
```

Comment: thanks, i knwo. but then i don't get the nicely formatted xticklabels with monthly ticks and the year below january

Comment: I did find a straight `pandas` solution. I've added it as another answer. I'm happy to delete this one if it would reduce confusion.